# How to transfer code from webots to a real e-puck2 robot?

Tags: webots

According to https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/epuck#bluetooth-remote-control I can remotely control from webots e-puck robots. I have e-puck2 robots, can I do it for this version of robots?
Or can I cross-compile it and upload to e-puck2?
If yes, please tell me in more detail how.

Answer (score 1):

You can remote control e-puck1 robots from Webots with Bluetooth only.
You can remote control e-puck2 robots from Webots with Bluetooth and Wi-Fi.
You can cross-compile Webots controllers to e-puck1 robots.
There is no official support for cross-compiling Webots controllers e-puck2 robots.
However, if you want to cross-compile Webots controllers to e-puck2 robots, it is possible by setting-up the e-puck2 cross-compiler and writting a small wrapper library allowing the cross-compilation from Webots controllers to e-puck2. This wrapper library should be inspired from the e-puck1 wrapper library allowing to cross-compile e-puck1 controllers.